# Paypal SDK Ruby error when including library in rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am trying to use the gem.

First I install the gem:

```
gem 'paypal-sdk-rest', :git => 'https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Ruby-SDK.git'
```

Then I run

bundle
Also I tried

`bundle install` and `bundle update`

Then I include my gem into the controller and include the REST Lib to make it Work

```
def doPayment
    require 'paypal-sdk-rest'
    include PayPal::SDK::REST
end
```

But when i run doPayment I receive the following error (Note that i am not doing any payment yet, just initializing the libraries)

```
undefined method `include' for #<UsuarioController:0x007f2b210da040>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you forgot to run this command - rails g paypal:sdk:install

Comment: @Emmanuel . Is my below answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this directly `include PayPal::SDK::REST` in controller instead of adding in controller method like an example,

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
include PayPal::SDK::REST
```